# How to select a particular dropdown when an option is selected in other dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

2 dropdowns with similar options but 1 change in options. In the first dropdown Audi exists but not in second dropdown.

This selects the same option in each dropdowns when selected as required.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cars1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cars2">
  <option value="">Please-Select</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
</select>
```

```
$(document).on('change', '[name="cars"]', function(){
  $('[name="cars"]').val( $(this).val() );
})
```

When I select the “Audi” option, how do I select “Please-Select” option while retaining the current functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you comment, you need *both* selects to be linked in/out.

I have added IDs to both selects for a easier selection, and an attribute for the targeted select. Then you test the selected option in its targeted select. If it exists, select it. If not, select the default option.

This way of testing against an existing match will allow to add values without worrying about the second select or differences.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
$('select').on('change', function() {
  // the value of the selected select
  var selected_select = $(this).attr('id');
  //  the value of the targeted select
  var selected_target = $(this).attr('data-target');
  // the value of the option
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();

   // check if the targeted value exists (true / false)
   var targetedValue = $('#'+selected_target+' option[value='+selectedValue+']').length > 0;

  $('#'+selected_select+' option[value='+selectedValue+']').prop('selected', true);

    // if value exists (true) then mark it as selected, else, pick the default option
    if(targetedValue === true) { 
      $('#'+selected_target+' option[value='+selectedValue+']').prop('selected', true);
    } else { 
      //$('#'+selected_target+' option[value=""]').attr('selected','selected');
      $('#'+selected_target+' option[value=""]').prop('selected', true);
    }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="cars1">Choose a car:</label>
    <select name="cars1" id="cars1" data-target="cars2">
    <option value="">Please-Select</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <label for="cars2">Choose a car:</label>
    <select name="cars2" id="cars2" data-target="cars1">
    <option value="">Please-Select</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="mclaren">McLaren</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: It’s working but I had to retain the function of both the dropdowns where 1st dropdown also triggered when an option is selected in 2nd dropdown & makes the 1st dropdown select the same option.

Comment: Maybe you should update your question and clarify this because this is not a parameter we could guess, and there's no default option in first select.

Comment: @cvz : after your comment, I updated my answer to match your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the selectors, to select by `ID`.

Saved the selected value in a variable, and on change, checking if the value is *audi*, then the selected value on the second `select="cars"` will be the empty value, which is `Please-select`.

**NOTES:**

1. Added a new function when the page is loaded, to change the value of the second `select` as the first one. Deleting this function won't affect your requirements. Feel free to modify it as you like.
2. The `for` attribute is to target the input that related to `label`, and it has to be the `id` of the target `input` which is a unique value, so I changed the `for` attributes values to match the `id`'s of the `inputs`.

```
<label for="cars1">Choose a car:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cars1">
...
</select>

<label for="cars2">Choose a car:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cars2">
...
</select>
```

3. Keep in mind, that technically, it is possible to have two inputs with the same `name` attribute in an HTML form. However, it can lead to unexpected behavior when submitting the form.

**The Code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var selectedValue = $('[id="cars1"]').val();
  $('[id="cars2"]').val(selectedValue === 'audi' ? '' : selectedValue);
});

$(document).on('change', '[id="cars1"]', function(){
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();
  $('[id="cars1"]').val(selectedValue);
  $('[id="cars2"]').val(selectedValue === 'audi' ? '' : selectedValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="cars1">Choose a car:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cars1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label for="cars1">Choose a car:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cars2">

  <option value="">Please-Select</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: It’s working but I had to retain the function of both the dropdowns where 1st dropdown also triggered when an option is selected in 2nd dropdown & makes the 1st dropdown select the same option, with the code you wrote 2nd dropdown not triggering the 1st dropdown.